# Eclipse EGL on GAE

Tags: google-app-engine, servlets

I created a Java servlet that works in Tomcat. All I do is to place some .jar dependencies in the lib folder of my Tomcat and create/add the following snippet in the web.xml file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<web-app xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee"
xmlns:web="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd"
xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee
http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd" version="2.5">
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>egl</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.eclipse.epsilon.egl.servlet.EglServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>egl</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>*.egl</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

I place an index.egl file in my webapps directory and whenever I call that .egl file it calls the EglServlet class (it's one of my jar files). Everything works fine in Tomcat.

I tried to create a Google App Engine and later a Heroku app following the same steps but the servlet fails. I mean that it loads the index.egl file as a plain text file. So, if the content of the file is [%="Hello World"%] it doesn't print a Hello World string as it's normal behaviour (and the behaviour I see in Tomcat) but it prints the whole command ([%="Hello World"%]).

I later realized that GAE and Heroku use Jetty and not Tomcat and I believe that I follow the wrong steps in delpoing my jars and placing the web.xml snippet. I place the index.egl file in the webapps folder. I create a WEB-INF folder in the webapps folder. A lib folder containing all my jars in that WEB-INF folder and a web.xml file with the snippet above in the WEB-INF folder. I also placed my jar files in the Jetty/lib folder.

What am I doing wrong? Is the file placement wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've found the solution. Apparently Google App Engine uses Jetty and not Tomcat as I initially thought. Although, Jetty is compatible with Tomcat it seems that there’s a small inconsistency in the way Tomcat and Jetty handle leading "/" characters in URL. So, I had to change the code in my servlet to lead to the correct path.